# Finding the second derivative

Tags: calculus

I have this question: 
Show that 
$$
\frac{\partial^2r}{\partial x^2} = \frac{y^2}{r^3}
$$
in two ways:
(1) find the $x$ derivative of 
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$
and (2) find the $x$ derivative of 
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{r}
$$
by the chain rule.

I am quite lost.  I mean I can take the $x$ derivative of the two equations, but I don't seem to in any way connect it to 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2} = \frac{y^2}{r^2}.
$$

Can anybody help?

- David

**EDIT**
It is supposed to be 
$$
r^3
$$
in the denominator.

Comment: I assume $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $r^3$ in the denominator?

Comment: The question is written as it says in the book. I dont know what r is, the question does not say anything other than what I have written.

Comment: What do you get when you take the derivative of $\frac{x}{r}$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: Is this question part of a group where the instructions for the set defines "r"?  That sure looks like a typo in the denominator to me if "r" is intended to be the radius variable in, say, polar coordinates (this is a fairly standard partial differentiation question).  [That _should_ be $ \ r^3 \ $ in the second derivative expression.]

Comment: It is supposed to be x^3 in the denominator. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \cdot 1 - x \cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}}{\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2} \\
&= \frac{(x^2 + y^2) - x^2}{\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^3} \\
&= \frac{y^2}{r^3}
\end{align}
$$
**(2)**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{x}{r} \right) \\
&= \frac{r \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} - x \cdot \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}}{r^2} \\
&= \frac{r - x \cdot \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}}{r^2} \\
&= \frac{r - x \cdot \frac{x}{r}}{r^2} \\
&= \frac{r^2 - x^2}{r^3} \\
&= \frac{y^2}{r^3} \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can you explain what happens from $$ \frac{\delta}{\delta x} (\frac{x}{r}) $$ to the next step?

Comment: It is the application of the Quotient Rule: the partial differentiation with respect to $ \ x \ $ ends up here looking pretty much like the way it would look for the function of a single variable.

Comment: I will edit my answer to include an intermediate step that explicitly uses the quotient rule.

Comment: The main point is that the $r$ is a function of $x$ (it depends on $x$), so you cannot ignore $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ when it shows up.

Comment: By the way, user1090614, the partial derivative symbol in $\LaTeX$ is $\textrm{\partial}$.

Comment: Ah!! r should not be treated as a constant, but rather as a function!! Now I can see how you use the quotient rule. What exactly is the value of $$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} $$?

Comment: The derivative of $x$ with respect to $x$ is the constant function $1$.

Comment: Okay, I have one last question: how do you go from $$ r^2-x^2 $$ to $$ y^2 $$ ?

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem!  $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$.  (This is the basic relationship between the Cartesian coordinates $x$ and $y$ and the polar radius $r$.)

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if you feel like it is.